# bullet_migration: electric and fuerte compatibility

Tags: ros, bullet, ros-electric, ros-fuerte, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to upgrade a project from Electric to Fuerte while still maintaining Electric compatibility (some systems will be on Electric for a while). I ran into an issue with tf and bullet. In the following code section, I need R defined as a btMatrix3x3 in Electric, but a tf::Matrix3x3 in Fuerte. Is there any way to have one set of code that will satisfy both? I would like to stay with the recommended Fuerte form, but I need it to work in both versions.

```
//world_to_camera is a tf::StampedTransform
//Electric version
btMatrix3x3 R;
R.setRotation(world_to_camera.inverse().getRotation());
```

Edit: In Electric, the error comes at tf::Matrix3x3 (Matrix3x3 is not a member of tf). In Fuerte, the error is at R.setRotation (no matching function call btMatrix3x3::setRotation(tf::Quaternion, can't convert tf::Quaternion to btQuaternion.) I tried putting .toBt() after .getRotation() in the migration guide, but I got the error Class tf::Quaternion has no member toBt.

I tried to follow the bullet_migration guide. The sed script doesn't work because it breaks in Electric. I'm sorry if this answer is obvious somewhere. Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40788/bullet_migration:-electric-and-fuerte-compatibility/) by [bwasserm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2506/bwasserm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can switch between fuerte and electric with the following code:

```
#if ROS_VERSION_MINIMUM(1,8,0)
  tf::Matrix3x3 R;      
#else
  btMatrix3x3 R;
#endif

R.setRotation(world_to_camera.inverse().getRotation());
```

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-07**:
Alternatively, if you have many occurrences of btMatrix3x3, you can put a typedef in a header file that defines tf::Matrix3x3 for older ros versions.

**Comment by [bwasserm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2506/bwasserm/) on 2012-08-08**:
Thanks, that worked. Except you got the types backwards, but I got the idea of what you meant.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-08-08**:
Ah right - I'll edit that. You should also consider what Lorenz wrote, in case you have multiple occurrences.

**Comment by [bwasserm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2506/bwasserm/) on 2012-08-08**:
Cool. And I would, but for some reason its only the one definition that causes problems. It is probably the right way to go though.